# Get node_type entity for default value in form

Tags: 8, forms, entities

I'm attempting to allow users to enter a number of node types in an entity reference field inside a custom config form. However I can't seem to supply it with a proper default value. My field in the form looks like this:

```
$config = $this->config('contentform.settings');
    $form['content_types'] = [
        '#type'          => 'entity_autocomplete',
        '#description'   => t('Choose what content types to map'),
        '#target_type'   => 'node_type',
        '#default_value' => $config->get('content_type'),
    ];
```

However $config->get('content_type') only supplies me with the label of the content type.

So I get the following error

> InvalidArgumentException: The #default_value property has to be an
>   entity object or an array of entity objects

I'm saving the value in the submit function like so:

```
    $content_type = $form_state->getValue('content_types');
    $this->config('contentform.settings')
         ->set('content_type', $content_type)
         ->save();
```

I've also tried $form_state->get('content_types') and $form_state->get('content_types')->entity; But those didn't work either.

How would I get the node_type entity or object instead of just the label? Or is there a way to load the node_type from just the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load a `node_type` entity by specifying the node type id

```
$node_type_entity = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::load($node_type_id);
```

or if you have multiple node types an array of entities:

```
$node_type_entities = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::loadMultiple($node_type_ids);
```

Comment: How would I get the id if it's based on input from an entity reference autocomplete field?

Comment: In configuration you store the id's, which are the machine names of the content types.